# Continuity and existence of directional derivatives at all directions of a $f:\mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y)=\frac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $f(x,y)=
    \begin{cases}
      \frac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2} & if & (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
      0       & if & (x,y)=(0,0) . 
\end{cases}$

(i) Prove the directional derivatives of $f$ exist in any direction at the point $(0,0)$.

(ii)¿Is $f$ continuous on (0,0)?

For (i) I took $u=(u_{1},u_{2}) \in \mathbb{R^{2}}$ such $\|u\|=1$ and $0=(0,0)$. So $$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(0+ t u)-f(0)}{t}=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{2(tu_{1})^2 (tu_{2})}{(tu_{1})^4+(tu_{2})^2}=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{(t^2 u_{1}^2)(t^2 u_{1}^{2}) tu_{2}}{t^{4}u_{1}^{4}+t^{2} u_{2}^{2}}.$$ But I cannot find the limit when $t$ aproaches to $0$. Which by finding them I would prove the directional derivative exist at every direction right?

For (ii) I got the intuition $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$ so I took $\lbrace (\frac{1}{k},\frac{1}{k}) \rbrace_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\lbrace (\frac{1}{k},0) \rbrace_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ which are two different sequences in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ converging to $(0,0)$. However, $\lbrace f(\frac{1}{k},\frac{1}{k}) \rbrace_{k \in \mathbb{N}}=\lbrace \frac{1}{k^{2}} \rbrace_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \to 0$ and $\lbrace f(\frac{1}{k},0) \rbrace_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \to 0$. So maybe my intuition was not right? Can anyone help me end the proof of continuity or not continuity , please?

Comment: The powers in your very first line do not seem to match those in which you have the limits. If they were the same, you could use your user name, i.e. take $u_1=\cos\theta$ and $u_2=\sin\theta$.

Comment: Has not this question being asked a bazillion times?

(i) Is is $x^2 + y^2$ or $x^4+y^2$ in the denominator? In the latter case, I believe there are not directional derivatives.
(ii) Consider something of the form $x = \sqrt{t}, y = t.$

Comment: Is $x^{2}+y^{2}$ in the denominator? I have seen other similar functions but still cannot solve for this specific one :( .For (ii) you mean those values as sequences? @WillM.

Comment: By substituting $x=\sqrt{t}$ and $y=t$ in $f(x,y)=f(\sqrt{t}, t)$ i got $f(\sqrt t, t)=1$, so How can i conclude f is not continuous at  (0,0)? @WillM.

Comment: $f(0,0)=0$ ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Take the limit as $(x,mx)\to 0$ along the line $y=mx$.

Comment: @YadatiKiran It didn't seems to work :(

Comment: @Cos: the limit I mentioned was for continuity $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,mx\to(0,0))}\dfrac{2x^2mx}{x^2(1+m^2)}\to0=f(0,0)$. So $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Directional derivative is defined as $$D_\vec{u}f(x,y)=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(x+ah,y+bh)-f(x,y)}{h} $$ where $\vec{u}=\langle a,b\rangle$ is the unit vector along which rate of change of $f(x,y)$ is calculated.

$$\displaystyle D_\vec{u}f(0,0)=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\dfrac{2(ah)^2(bh)}{(ah)^2+(bh)^2}-0}{h}= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{2a^2b}{a^2+b^2}$$ which exists since $||\vec{u}||=1\implies a^2+b^2\neq0$. So directional derivatives of $f$ exist in any direction at the point $(0,0)$ since limit is independent of how $h$ approaches $0$.

To calculate continuity let $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ along $y=mx$ where $m$ is a constant.

$$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,mx\to(0,0))}\dfrac{2x^2mx}{x^2(1+m^2)}=\lim_{\substack{x\to 0\\\text{along y=mx}}}\dfrac{2mx}{(1+m^2)}=0=f(0,0)$$

So $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.